# Intellij : Running one Cucumber Examples in Scenario Outline like I run a Scenario

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm, intellij-plugin, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

In Intellij I want to Run one "Examples" in "Scenario Outline" like I right-click and run a "Scenario". When I try that at present it runs all examples and one of the step in the junit result page has a rotating wheel even after completion. What am I missing (I dont want to edit run configuration everytime)?

I can run it using normal junit as well - but the problem is I cannot double click on the step in the junit pane and go to the feature file step

For example I want to right click and run @case2 Examples in the following

`Scenario Outline: Perform Some examples of Similar scenario`

`Given I do <something>`

`@case1`

`Examples:`

`|something |`

`|case1     |`

`@case2`

`Examples:`

`|something |`

`|case      |`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to either run the example from the command line by specifying the line number (something like `path/file.feature:8`, or adding tags to the specific example(s) you want to run and specify which tags to run in your runner.